# What does the question mark at the end of filenames mean?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In some project I've met these lines:

```
$.get("defaults/data.json?", ...);
$.get("defaults/structure.html?", ...);
$.get("defaults/style.css?", ...);
```

On server side these files without any extra symbols, so
I'm wondering what does the question mark at the end of files mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `?` in a URL denotes the start of the query string.  A `?` at the end with no variables following it is usually an unnecessary way of saying "this has absolutely no querystring".

It would be possible with a URL rewriting engine for example, to examine the incoming REQUEST_URI to see if it ends with `?` and take a different action than requests not ending in `?`, but that would be an unusual usage. It would much more common to just specify some value in the query string.

Comment: In this case the query string may be constructed from parameters given in the second argument to the `get()` function (see [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)).

Answer (score 5):

"?" is the separator for supplying arguments via a GET request.

Comment: Not necessarily - you can send a querystring in a POST (or any other) request as well. See RFC2616: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1

Comment: It's more of an unintended side effect IMHO; but it works across the browsers and servers I've seen so far.

Answer (score 2):

? states you're providing arguments via HTTP GET.

For example if you want to send a=1 and b=2 , you would do http://mysite.com/myfile.php?a=1&b=2

Shai.